# Position:absolute element inside a div with overflow-y:auto does not show in the desired position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, sorry for the title gore, I didnt know how to put it on a couple of lines.

I have this situation:
[The div that overflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpa1k.png)

With this element:
[The absolute element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyOC.png)

The problem I face is this:
[As you can see when I hover the tooltip of the element is positioned in the "real" position of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWqow.png)

When the element that I hover is below the initial viewport of the DIV, the position of the absolute positioned element shows on the real position of the element (For real I mean, if the overflow-y: auto was not set), visual example:

[Without overflow it works as I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMBsG.png)

Sorry for the crap explanation, I tried my best. Hope with the images it is clear.

Here is some code, the html:
[This is the tooltip that is not positioned in the right place when it is on and element lower than the 300px of the container div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJyv8.png)

Comment: It's kind of hard to figure this out without any code.

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: It's pretty clear what the problem is, but there could be a bunch of causes, and a bunch of solutions. A bit of code would go a long way.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan im sorry, but why the code is important here? Its just and element called Y with display:none, inside element called X, when the X is hovered the Y displays:block

Comment: Although just at a glance, I'd recommend adding `position: relative;` to the overflowing element

Comment: @Josepv, the code is important for therein lies the problem you are facing. (I loved that sentence :))

Comment: @YaakovAinspan  after adding position:relative, now the element is in the right place, but obiously is cut in half because it has a margin-left: -30 that goes beyond the parent. The problem with the code is that is HTML inside PHP that is send to a yii2 framework widget, but I will edit and try to show it.

Comment: Maybe set `overflow-x: visible` to allow it to overflow the x axis, but keep the `overflow-y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is not clear. If you are using absolute positioning in any of the element in your project then you cant overflow your element in either of the x or y axis. If you want to do so then you can position your elements in relative. Hope that answers your query. if not kindly share your work to make me understand better.